# proper malloc bug fixing

Tags: c, malloc

I had this line of code :

```
conf->table = malloc(sizeof(struct Categorie)*(csv_nbLines(filename)));
```

that led to a bug when calling `free()` on `conf` because `struct Categorie` include a string (array of `char`s).

I fixed the bug by replacing the `sizeof(struct Categorie)` with `30` because I know the said string will not go over 30 bytes.

Is this acceptable ? If not what would be a better way to `malloc` the exact amount of memory needed ?

**EDIT** :

```
struct Categorie {
    char *name;
    char c;
};
```

**EDIT2** :

I end up with this and it works perfectly (the names speaks for themselves).

in `conf_init()`

```
conf->table = malloc(sizeof(struct Categorie))
```

in `conf_load()` where `pch` is a string returned by `strtok()`

```
conf->table[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(pch));
conf->table[i].name = pch;
```

I hope this is enough explanation for the next one :)

Comment: you could try `free(conf->table)` instead.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Categorie`; it is possible that your bugfix is unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: RE: Update: 1) Make that `conf->table[i].name = malloc(1+strlen(pch));`  [ sizeof(char) is 1, by definition, the extra character is needed for the terminating NUL ] 2) `conf->table[i].name = pch;` You cannot copy strings by assignment, use strcpy() or memcpy() or, in this case strdup()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid, NO.

Assuming the *string* you mentioned is in form of

```
struct Categorie
{

.
.
char * str;
}
```

You're supposed to first `malloc()` the memory for `conf->table` with `sizeof(struct Categorie)`, and then, `malloc()` for `conf->table->str`.

Not to mention, `free()`ing also required, in the exact opposite oreder of allocation, i.e, first you need to free `conf->table->str` and then `conf->table`.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** No. That is not acceptable.

You need to provide more code to understand what is going on, but assuming `conf->table` is `struct Categorie *` then there's something pretty rotten.

If that isn't the type then it's not clear why you ever thought `sizeof(struct Categorie)` might be the answer.